# How to create custom opt-in email for webforms

Tags: webform-civicrm

I've seen the option to double opt-in (send a confirmation email) when choosing a public group in webform, but I'd like to be able to:

- customise the confirmation email sent
- have a double opt-in for private emails

Is there a way to do that in webform civi?
I tried to find a checksum token to be used in a custom email, does it exist?

Alternatively, is there a webform specific confirmation page that I could use? eg. https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_confirm_email

Answer (score 3):

You can daisy-chain webforms using checksums, so on form 1 you set up your fields to collect contact detail data, then set up a second webform which actually adds them to your private email group, and having set the second webform up you can find the url with checksum on the CiviCRM tab of the webform, and then set that as the link that goes out in the email from the first webform.

Comment: To be sure I understand: So the user would end up on the second "confirm" webform, but would still have to click on the submit button to properly register?

Comment: Yes true. We haven't used this approach for what you are doing. we have used it where we are signing people up and on the second form getting extra info, giving them a drupal account etc.

Comment: by checksum. you mean the one from {contact.checksum}? how can I access this from within a mail sent by webform?

Comment: AH true i think I have skipped a step. You need to add the checksum field on the form 1, hidden, and set it in to the path in the email that will take them to form2. Then in form2, in the vertical tabs on the civicrm tab of the webform is a section called Additional Options, if you click on that you should see something like "To have this form auto-filled for anonymous users, enable the "Existing Contact" field for New Member and send the following link from CiviMail:
<site>/<path>/<node-title>?cid1={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}". Does that make more sense, if so i will update answer

Comment: should have mentioned i tried it and works fine when you send the email from civi. but doesn't when you send it from webmail directly. when you chained the two forms. did you send an email between the two steps?

Comment: THe link i have go out from Form 1 linking to Form 2 is something like this Please visit this page to confirm your registration:

http://<site>/node/<id>?cid1=[submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_fieldset_fieldset:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_contact_id:nolabel]&cs1=[submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_fieldset_fieldset:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_cs:nolabel]

Comment: In fact, if you add the 'contact id' and 'checksum' values for the contact in the civicrm tab, and edit the webform components that it creates, there are instructions there on how to do this.

Comment: This sounds like a method for avoiding the default opt-in confirmation message, and thereby enabling a more customisable approach, such as having different emails for different groups etc. I guess you could also get the webforms to create activity records so you have an explicit record for the sign up and confirmation? Maybe more GDPR-friendly.

Comment: sure the webform can create an Activity for every form submission