# How can I configure the automated messages such that when someone sings up to list A they get message A, and for list B, they get message B?

Tags: civimail, groups, confirmation

When someone signs up to a Civi mailing list group through a profile or webform, they get sent the default automated subscription confirmation message.

Is there any way of customising that message such that different messages can be sent based on the group/s that are being signed up to?

This looks like it might be a useful way to get around the limitations of CiviCRM in this respect? [How to create custom opt-in email for webforms](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/how-to-create-custom-opt-in-email-for-webforms)

Comment: Can you turn of the automated sub and then use CiviRules to fire out an email based on which Group you added them to? I don't think webform emails can easily change message based on conditions

Comment: Thanks Pete. I think CiviRules could do it. In terms of customising webform email content based on conditions, it can be done by putting the variable content into hidden fields in the form and adding the token for the hidden field in the email.

Comment: good to hear of that approach to webform and conditionals. makes sense. have put civirules as a potential answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps turn off the automated sub and then use CiviRules to fire out an email based on which Group you added them to.